# PhpStorm resets code style settings when reopening project

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

PhpStorm can't save code style settings in project.

I've changed settings to use Double quotes in HTML. The Single quote option is still selected when I close and reopen the project.

The following `<option name="HTML_QUOTE_STYLE" value="Single" />` line keeps returning in `.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml` file when opening the project.

I've also tried copying code style settings from the IDE and saving it in `.editorconfig` file...

Comment: What is you PhpStorm version?

Comment: Sounds similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-311315/Code-Style-doesnt-work-anymore-after-IntelliJ-restart-since-version-2023.1-EAP